# How to find the size of these RAM sticks?

Tags: memory, ddr

Some time ago I cleaned up mess in my room and found 2 RAM chips. Can I find out somehow how much memory it contains without pluging it in the computer?

p.s It seems, both of the chips are DDR.

1. One of it is Samsung and has the following text on each subchip it contains:
   SAMSUNG     428
   K4H560838E-TCCC
   H56 8 BEF986BA
2. The second one is HYNIX and has this text on each subchip:
   HYNIX 147A
   HY5DU28822AT-H
   KOREA 7E80256M

Comment: I believe the Hynix is 256MB and according to [OverClokers forum](http://www.overclockers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=309478) the Samsung chip is 512MB

Comment: Took all of about 30 seconds of googling

Answer (score 3):

Google'd the part numbers:

- [K4H560838E-TCCC](https://www.google.com/search?q=K4H560838E-TCCC) for Samsung and found 256 MB from [here](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/109714/SAMSUNG/K4H560838E.html) and [here](http://www.memoryten.com/pc/005935/Chips-DDR-256Mbit/)
- [HY5DU28822AT-H](https://www.google.com/search?q=HY5DU28822AT-H) for Hynix and found 128 MB 
  from [here](http://www.digchip.com/datasheets/parts/datasheet/202/HY5DU28822AT-H.php)
  and [here](http://doc.chipfind.ru/hynix/hy5du28822ath.htm)

With older memory there may be wrong data on the Internet. Only sure way would be to install in a system and check on the BIOS screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Brad! Assuming that hynix has chips on both sides it is 256? Or still 128?

Comment: Can you expand on what you Google'd for to locate the sticks?

Comment: It seems @Darius has another info about these sticks...

Comment: updated with more info

Comment: What is funny that the first link to the Samsung chip claims it is 512MB and the second link says 256.... Which one is it then ? :D

Comment: Looks like the root 'K4H560838E' matches a number of sticks. The TCCC seems to have more 256MB matches. So the belmont tech link may be wrong. Updated the answer with a different link.